# Finite series for 4x4 matrix exponential of anti-Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Based on the Cayley Hamilton theorem, one would expect an order 4 matrix polynomial formula for the matrix exponential of a 4x4 matrix.

Is this polynomial known? Does it simplify in any way in the case of the exponential of an anti-Hermitian matrix?

Comment: The Cayley-Hamilton theorem does not play as nicely with the exponential function as you might expect.

Comment: Does this happen to be a real matrix?

Comment: it could be real or complex, just in $\mathfrak{su}(4)$.

Comment: I'm certain I saw a claim that someone found this series in an obscure indian journal one time, but I lost it...